# how to send a JSON object from contentURL : data.url("foo.html") to contentScript

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I tried using `window.postMessage` but this only sends a variable (containing string) to the contentScript. But I want to send a number of variables' values. This seems to be possible by using a JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `JSON.stringify()` to turn the object into a string:

```js
var data = {a: 1, b: 2};
window.postMessage(JSON.stringify(data), "*");
```

On the other end use `JSON.parse()` to reverse the process:

```js
var data = JSON.parse(message);
```

Comment: Thanx for the quick help. However, I get this error after following your instructions : uncaught exception: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

Comment: How about doing `console.log(message)` and having a look at whatever is being parsed there?

Comment: well here is the contentScript code :The variable I am parsing contains a very long string. Here is a part of that string that can be shown in the less space available in this comment box : value to be de-stringified : {"fromDirection":"fromDirection","topColorSelected":false,"autoGenerateSelected":false,"linearSelected":true,"colorStopTop":2.79,"lowerColor":"green","redTop":210,"greenTop":227,"blueTop":250,"topHexColor":"d2e3fa","formattedText":"background-color:#d2e3fa;

Comment: Pastebin the whole thing? Or Gist?

Comment: I took your string, stringified it, then parsed it using Firefox's web console. I didn't get that error. I whipped up this quick test as well: https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/addon/1037897/latest/

Comment: Well you tested 'stringify'where as stringify is ok with me also. I get error only when I parse the stringified thing to convert back to JSON. (plz refer to the pastebin for the code)

Comment: well I changed my course of action. I removed window.postMessage. Instead I have used port.emit. For this I had to shift my JS code of html into a separate JS file and then load it in the content script's data.url. I managed to send color values from a colorpicker in the panel. However, the messaging seems to be quite slow as I see that the colorpicker haults during operation. The colorpicker definitely sends data at high rate as I drag its picker. colorpicker is http://bgrins.github.com/spectrum/. Any ideas how to fix ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use:

`self.port.emit('some-event', object)`

...and only send objects that can be serialized into JSON properly, the SDK will handle serialization and parsing for you. Here's a quick builder example that illustrates this:

https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/addon/1036506/latest/

I had thought that postMessage would be the same?

Comment: I am actually sending message from a JS file included in an html file which I load through data.url. I tried self.port.emit ,however, it was not recognized there. Got error.

Comment: Ah, yes: self.port isn't defined in your page's DOM. Here's a builder example that passes an event from a page back to the addon code through a content script: https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/addon/1036644/latest/

Comment: Thats right. But I am successful in communicating from html file to page-mod add-on script. I used window.postMessage for this. However, I can only send strings by this method where as I want to send JSON.

Comment: Ah, ok - You just need to stringify your data first and then parse it on the other side, as Wladimir suggested earlier.

Comment: finally I am working on a work around. I have managed to transfer a string into the contentScript of the panel from index.html. Now i want to split the string to get different parts of it. I tried using .split() and .slice() but I get error which says that they are not functions. Any ideas ?

Comment: Is it actually a string? If you are using postMessage, I thought the payload was an event object, so you want to access the payload with event.data.

Comment: payload is from index.html (via wndows.pastMessage) and received in cntentScript. The code in contentScript is : window.addEventListener('message', function(StringFromIndex){ var   arrayFromIndex=StringFromIndex.split('');

Comment: you are right.I am getting an event in the contentScript. Event.data gives me top,false,false as the data. Now I want to convert this data into an array by splitting the words separated by commas. The data doesnt seem to be a true string thats why .split(",") is giving error that it is not a function.

Comment: That would be: var s = new String(ev.data).split(','); right?